# Still try read latitude of undefined even if i declared typeof !== undefined

Tags: node.js, geocoding

```
 UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next){
     const code = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
     console.log(this.address)
     console.log(code)
```

so I was having this trouble  a time ago so I tried to do this :

```
     if(typeof code !== "undefined"){
         this.lat = code[0].latitude
         this.lng = code[0].longitude
     }
```

but it still returns :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
```

Comment: Not `code` is undefined, but `code[0]`, if you read the error carefully. What does `console.log(code)` reveal? Does `code` always have a `0` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could also check if code is an array and has at least one element like:

if (Array.isArray(code) && code[0]) {
... do something ...
}

Comment: `code.length` checks if `code` has at least one element, not `code[0]`. `code[0]` checks if element `0` of `code` is truthy, which isn’t the case in every scenario.

Comment: Sure, if you assume that code can contain of anything linke string, numbers etc. second condition must be ```typeof code[0] === 'object'``` to be exact and to catch all "truthy" values that are no object. But I am pretty sure the short form is as good as well, especcially if you assume that the elements of ```code``` are either objects or null/undefined.